# Is it right to use a struct instead of giving a constructor 8 arguments?

Tags: c#, oop, struct, readability

I was just thinking,

if I need to write a constructor for let's say an `Apartment` class,
and the apartment class has several of properties such as `ApartmentSize`, `NumberOfBedrooms`, `NumberOfShowers`, `CurrentMarketValue`, `PurchasePrice` etc.

Will it be more readable to create a struct that is called, let's say, `ApartmentProperties` and to have all of the above properties as members of this struct, so when I need to construct an apartment, all the constructor requires is just this struct?

If not, what would be a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: Yes, such a wrapper class is a good approach when you have to pass around many related parameters.

Comment: Is it not reasonable to give the constructor no arguments, and set the values via properties, with appropriate defaults in each case if you don't set them?

Comment: @ClickRick you mean that the constructor will set all of the data members with 0's and nulls and then I would set the real values using setter?

Comment: Why struct and not class ? Value types (aka structs) should be used with few properties (2-3)... 8 seems a bit too much to me...

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Whether it is appropriate could well depend on the application, but creating a new record when an estate agent is about to visit a property could be one where missing values are entirely plausible, and take the special meaning of "I don't yet know". -1 might be an appropriate default for "number of showers" in case there really are none, where zero would be a valid entry.

Comment: What you are doing is called Cohesion in software engineering so combine different related properties like purchase price,sale price and make struct or class of them since that will be more maintainable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems a bit circular. You've got an object whose constructor needs all these values, so you're creating an object to contain them. So now you've got a struct that needs all these values... how do you create the struct?

You're proposing this:

```
ApartmentProperties props = new ApartmentProperties(size, numBedrooms, numShowers, marketValue, purchasePrice);
Apartment apt = new Apartment(props);
```

It seems no different to doing this:

```
Apartment apt = new Apartment(size, numBedrooms, numShowers, marketValue, purchasePrice);
```

If this is the only time you're using the `ApartmentProperties` struct, and all you're doing is putting all these values into it, passing it to a constructor, and then pulling them out again, then it feels unnecessary. It's just one more object to think about.

In the comments it's been suggested that if you don't like having so many parameters on the constructor, then you could do this:

```
Apartment apt = new Apartment();
apt.Size = size;
apt.NumBedrooms = numBedrooms;
apt.Numshowers = numShowers;
apt.MarketValue = marketValue;
apt.PurchasePrice = purchasePrice;
```

I'm not a huge fan of this approach. Now your constructor is smaller and tidier, yes, but all you've done is move the logic that was neatly wrapped up inside it out to wherever you're calling it from. This makes the calling code responsible for making sure that all the properties are properly assigned. I'd advise leaving the assignments in the constructor - it just lets you assume that an `Apartment` object has its properties assigned because you know the constructor will have done it.

Of course, there is a middle ground. You could take out *some* of the constructor parameters, leaving only those that *must* be there. For example, an apartment *always* has a size, a number of bedrooms, and a number of showers, but you might not know its current value or purchase price - perhaps someone's been living there a while and haven't had a valuation recently. In that case, you could cut the constructor down to just three parameters, and allow the calling code to assign the others *if* they're known. Or better yet, overload the constructor with varying numbers of parameters. Just make sure you have some way of telling for sure whether a value has been assigned (for example, there may be some weird cases in which a sale price of zero is valid, but perhaps you know that -1 is never going to be valid). If you need to be really sure, use `Nullable<T>` and return null if it's not been assigned yet.

Comment: +1, I discarded my answer when saw your sample code. It is what I was to say.

Comment: You can also use object initializers: `var apt = new Apartment { Size = size, NumBedrooms = numBedrooms, NumShowers = numShowsers, MarketValue = marketValue, PurchasePrice = purchasePrice };`. Saves you a few keystrokes and "groups" together the properties to initialize.

Comment: That works too, but it requires you to have a parameterless constructor, which runs into the problems I mentioned about leaving the initialisation up to the calling code. If you want to *guarantee* that an `Apartment` instance will have certain values set (size, number of rooms etc) then you need to leave the parameterless constructor private.

Comment: As I said in the comments on the question, the decision as to whether it is appropriate to do it one way or another could well depend on the application.

Comment: I just *love* how philosophic Object Oriented Design is, thanks! I feel much wiser after reading your answer.

Comment: Why are you saying that object initializers requires a parameterless constructor? Thats not true, you can write `new Foo(para1) { PropertyB = "HelloWorld", };`

Comment: You can, but that's not the syntax that knittl used ;)

Comment: @anaximander, so assuming I know I will always have the required arguments' value upon object creation, according to your approach, I should give the constructor as many arguments as it needs, right?

Comment: @Quaker: Generally speaking, yes. The alternatives all either move too much logic out of your constructor to places you have less control over it, or they just end up duplicating work. If that particular collection of values is going to be passed to a lot of other things, then maybe that would justify having a container for it, but here it's just unnecessary complexity. If you want to help the readability, maybe format your code so that the parameters form a vertical list, and make sure the arguments and the variables passed to them are named something self-explanatory.

Comment: @anaximander: I'm a big fan of exposed-field structures, where every field has the same semantics: it simply holds the last thing someone put there.  Code which accepts such structures as parameters should specify what it wants the caller to put in the fields, and code that returns such structures should document what it puts in the fields, but the struct itself should simply be documented as an aggregation of fields since all the logic would be in the code that uses it.

Answer (score 2):

In first place I'd recommend you not to use `struct` at all. Instead `class` should be used.

[Value Type Usage Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y23b5415%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) states that

It is recommended that you use a struct for types that meet any of the following criteria:

1. Act like primitive types.
2. Have an instance size under 16 bytes.
3. Are immutable.
4. Value semantics are desirable.

8 fields is way big for a struct for perfomance reasons. Also refer [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/04/14/113365.aspx) for more info

Comment: Those guidelines are good for structs which are supposed to behave like objects.  If what is desired is not an "object", however, but a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape, one should use a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape rather than trying to use an object to emulate a bunch of variables of stuck together with duct tape, or wrapping a bunch of variables which are stuck together with duct tape in such a way as to emulate an object emulating a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a parameterless (default) constructor, and rely on the type initializer synctax instead to initialze properties:

```
public class Apartment
{
    public Apartment()
    {
        // set default values
    }

    // define properties
    public int NumberOfBedRooms { get; set; }
    // ...
}

var apt = new Apartment {
  ApartmentSize = 100,
  NumberOfBedrooms = 3,
  NumberOfShowers = 2,
  CurrentMarketValue = 100000m,
  PurchasePrice = 100000m
}
```

This way you don't have to write constructor overloads, and users of your class can determine what to initialize.

Answer (score 1):

A struct is, at its heart, a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape.  A struct with private fields may try to act like something else, but an struct with exposed public fields will act like a bunch of variable stuck together with duct tape.  In cases where one wants to stick a bunch of variables together with duct tape, an exposed-field struct is often a perfect fit.

Note that Microsoft's guidelines assume that code will want everything to behave like an `Object`; they were also written before .NET supported generic types, when things generally couldn't be stored in collections without first casting them to `Object`.  It is generally good to follow the guidelines in cases where one wants something whose semantics will be consistent with derivatives of `Object`(*).  One should not follow them, however, if what one wants is simply to have a storage location (field, variable, etc.) hold a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape.  Many of the guidelines are in fact backward when applied to that particular scenario.

(*) A structure type storage location does not hold a derivative of `Object`, nor a reference to one; instead, it holds the concatenated contents of the structure's public and private fields.  If a structure type is cast to a reference type, the system will create a new heap object with fields matching those of the structure, and copy the structure's fields to those of the new object; the resulting object will then behave largely as a class object with fields and methods matching those of the structure.  If a structure does not follow the MS guidelines, the storage-location type and heap type will behave differently; MS assumes that's always a bad thing, but if one wants a storage location to hold a bunch of variables stuck together with duct tape, it's more useful to have a struct which cleanly behaves like that (something class can't do) than one which pretends to be a class object doing its best (rather clunky) emulation of such a thing.

Passing a structure as a value parameter will have about the same cost as passing all of the structure's public and private fields individually.  Passing the struct as a reference parameter (either `ref` or `out`) has a fixed cost, regardless of the number of fields.  Calling an instance method on a mutable storage location of structure type is equivalent to calling a method with an extra parameter `ref StructType this` at the start of its parameter list; if one attempts to call `someStruct.Foo()` on a temporary or immutable location, the compiler will silently substitute `var temp = someStruct; temp.Foo();`; because there is (still!) no way to tell the compiler that such substitution cannot safely be applied to a particular method, one should generally avoid writing methods where such substitution would not be safe.

With regard to your particular scenario, I think a simple exposed-field struct would likely be just about perfect.  It allows parameter values to be set up in whatever sequence is convenient, makes it easy to construct multiple objects with similar but not identical parameters, etc.  From a performance standpoint, taking the struct as a `ref` parameter might sometimes be a little faster than passing by value, but unless the same structure is passed multiple times I would expect passing by value should be just fine (if you use an exposed-field struct, I would expect that the JITter could probably produce code that was roughly equivalent to passing each struct field as a separate argument).

Comment: I actually thought about it a lot. I was suggested to give the parameter list as is or wrapping it with a class. This is quite weird since wrapping it with a *class* means that the class will be passed by reference, while passing the values themselves will pass them by value. Should passing a struct by value, or passing the elements which the struct holds by reference cost the same?

Comment: @Quaker: Passing a structure by value is roughly equivalent to passing all the elements by value.  Passing anything by reference has a cost which is generally slightly higher than passing an integer by value.  I'm not sure what you mean by "passing the elements the struct holds by reference".  Also, note that classes are not "passed by references"; instead, class object references are generally passed by value (in a few cases, a class object reference may be passed by reference, but that's still not the same thing as passing the class by reference).  On the latter point...

Comment: @Quaker: I'd suggest that whenever you hear "object reference", think "object identifier" and things will be much clearer.  When a method takes a class-type argument, it is passed something that will identify an object of that class type (or else null).  A method which receives a parameter passed by reference cannot persist the reference once it leaves scope.  A method which receives an object identifier by value, however, can store that identifier for use later--behavior very different from "pass-by-reference" semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do this:

You should create a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    ...
    public int ApartmentSize{get;set;}
    ...
}
```

And in the Apartment class' constructor, do this:

```
Apartment(MyClass obj)
{
  // access the values like: obj.ApartmentSize  
}
```

`Struct` is overkill for this